# css binding with function that return false value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

How to apply css class 'notchanged'  if 'isDirty' function return false value?

```html
<input id="idname" data-bind="value: name, css: { changed: name.isDirty, notchanged : !name.isDirty  }" />
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please accept it.

Comment: I can't.
I not allowed. i just registered in stackoverflow.

Comment: My vote will be visible only after I get 15 points

Comment: Okay, you are another step closer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you just need to replace `isDirty` with `isDirty()` and class names should be inside quotes `'notchanged'`.

```
data-bind="value: name, css: {
    'changed' : name.isDirty(),
    'notchanged' : !name.isDirty()
}
```

or

```
<input id="idname" data-bind="value: name, css: name.isDirty() == true ? 'changed' : 'notchanged'" />
```